# understand better the item.url variable in ansible task

Tags: ansible

Could anyone explain me to understand why do I have **{{item.url}}** in the command ansible task ? I've lookup in the elasticsearch role but I didn't find any **"item.url"** variable declared

```
- name: Install elasticsearch plugins
  become: yes
  command: "{{es_home}}/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install {{ item.url | default(item.plugin) }} --batch --silent"
  register: plugin_installed
  changed_when: plugin_installed.rc|default(0) == 0
  with_items: "{{ es_plugins }}"
  when: item.plugin in plugins_to_install
  notify: restart elasticsearch
  environment:
    CONF_DIR: "{{ es_conf_dir }}"
    ES_PATH_CONF: "{{ es_conf_dir }}"
    ES_INCLUDE: "{{ default_file }}"
  until: plugin_installed.rc|default(0) == 0
  retries: 5
  delay: 5
```

AFAIK , if i'm installing manually the elasticsearch plugin I would use the below command:

```
/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install "name_of_plugin"
```

**or**

```
/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install "http://repo.xxxx/name_of_plugin.zip"
```

Comment: are you running this as a loop with the `loop: ` or equivalent syntax. `item` normally refers to the current item being iterated in a loop

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: [*`item`*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-simple-list) is the default  [*`loop variable`*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#defining-inner-and-outer-variable-names-with-loop-var). In the example below, the attribute *`url`* will be used if present. By default, the attribute *`plugin`* will be used

```yaml
    - command: "install {{ item.url|default(item.plugin) }}"
      loop:
        - plugin: plug1
        - plugin: plug2
          url: http://repo/plug2.zip
```

Details: Create the lists *`plugins_to_install`* and *`es_plugins`* for testing. The first two plugins will be installed. The *`plug2`* should be installed via *`url`*. Let's minimize the *`command`* task and focus on the attributes that are relevant to the question

- Remove: *`become, notify, environment`*
- Let's use *`echo`* to test the *`command`*
- Use [*loop*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loops) instead of *`with_items`*

The play below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    plugins_to_install: [plug1, plug2]
    es_plugins:
      - plugin: plug1
      - plugin: plug2
        url: http://repo/plug2.zip
      - plugin: plug3

  tasks:

    - command: "echo install {{ item.url|default(item.plugin) }}"
      loop: "{{ es_plugins }}"
      when: item.plugin in plugins_to_install
      register: plugin_installed
      changed_when: plugin_installed.rc|default(0) == 0
      until: plugin_installed.rc|default(0) == 0
      retries: 5
      delay: 5

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for p in plugin_installed.results|rejectattr('skipped', 'defined') %}
          {{ p.item.plugin }} rc: {{ p.rc }} cmd: "{{ p.cmd|join(' ') }}"
          {% endfor %}
```

shows the self-explaining output of debug

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'plugin': 'plug1'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'plugin': 'plug2', 'url': 'http://repo/plug2.zip'})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'plugin': 'plug3'}) 

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    plug1 rc: 0 cmd: "echo install plug1"
    plug2 rc: 0 cmd: "echo install http://repo/plug2.zip"

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```